# Select primary photo if exist else pick first uploaded photo

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve a single picture set by the user as the primary picture from table as below:

```
SELECT p.*, ph.* FROM place AS p 
  INNER JOIN photo as ph 
  ON p.place_id = ph.place_id
  WHERE ph.primary_pic = 'X';
```

But not all user has set their primary picture, resulting in the query does not return anything.

```
IF(query is empty)
  //perform SQL again with primary_pic = ''
```

Is there any ways or syntax that could be use to query this with one single SQL statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working in MS SQL but I don't see anything MS-specific except for the table variables. So if you change that to existing tables, it should run on MySQL too. (I am not sure but I guess MySQL should have EXCEPT set operation.)

```
-- sample data start
declare @place as table (plid int, plname nvarchar(100))
declare @photo as table (phid int, phname nvarchar(100), plid int, primary_pic nvarchar(1))

insert into @place values (1, 'aaa')
insert into @place values (2, 'bbb')
insert into @photo values (1, 'aaa_1.jpg', 1, '')
insert into @photo values (2, 'aaa_2.jpg', 1, 'X')
insert into @photo values (3, 'aaa_3.jpg', 1, '')
insert into @photo values (4, 'aaa_4.jpg', 1, '')
insert into @photo values (5, 'bbb_1.jpg', 2, '')
insert into @photo values (6, 'bbb_2.jpg', 2, '')
insert into @photo values (7, 'bbb_3.jpg', 2, '')
insert into @photo values (8, 'bbb_4.jpg', 2, '')
-- sample data end
-- note: @place and @photo are table variables in MS SQL

select p.*, ph2.* 
from @place p inner join @photo ph2 on p.plid = ph2.plid
inner join (
select ph.plid, ph.primary_pic, min(ph.phid) phid
from @photo ph inner join
(select distinct plid from @photo where primary_pic <> 'X'
    except 
    select distinct plid from @photo where primary_pic = 'X') hasnoprimary
    on hasnoprimary.plid = ph.plid
group by ph.plid, ph.primary_pic
union
select ph.plid, ph.primary_pic, min(ph.phid) phid
from @photo ph inner join
(select distinct plid from @photo where primary_pic = 'X') hasprimary
    on hasprimary.plid = ph.plid
where primary_pic = 'X'
group by ph.plid, ph.primary_pic
) trickypart on trickypart.phid = ph2.phid
```

Method: (1) get two lists of place IDs. One for which there is a primary photo and another for which there isn't (this is where I used EXCEPT). (2) join the photos table to both of them separately to get the photo IDs. For the first list, it is what was marked with X, for the second it is the minimum of all photo IDs. (3) make a union of the two. (4) join it back to places and photos.

In MS SQL it works ang gives the following for the sample data above:

```
plid        plname         phid        phname         plid        primary_pic
----------- -------------- ----------- -------------- ----------- -----------
1           aaa            2           aaa_2.jpg      1           X
2           bbb            5           bbb_1.jpg      2
```